# Video Problem on ASUS ROG G750JW with 23.04 & 23.10 Nightly Build

Tags: nvidia, asus

I have a ASUS ROG G750JW Laptop with an Nvidia 765M video card. I have not been able to use the 23.XX builds as it leaves the computer with the cursor in the upper right hand corner. I cannot type anything at the cursor or get the computers attention. I am using 22.04 with no issues and have never had issues with ubuntu on this machine. The current 22.04.3 is using the Nvidia 390 driver, but it worked with the Nouveau driver also. Any help would be appreciated. I tried the 23.10 Nightly build just to see if I could move to the 23.XX version of ubuntu. The 23.XX builds were installed from USB media as a fresh install. I amusing Ubuntu 22.04.3 desktop with linux kernel 6.2.0-33-generic

Comment: Your details are a little confusing to me, you don't specify which product of 22.04 but I assume desktop (*kernel stack my interest here & installation media dictates that*). Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS if using the HWE kernel uses the same 6.2 kernel as 23.04? so is that what you're using?  yet 23.04 doesn't work yet 22.04 does??  That is a huge clue if that's true, but you're unclear with specifics; so are you using the GA stack of 22.04 (ie. 5.15 kernel only).  Ubuntu *mantic* uses the 6.5 kernel (22.04 gets that at 22.04.4)

Comment: I am using 22.04.3 Desktop with 6.2.0-33 generic. This version of Ubuntu is flawless, I also used 22.10 which also worked great but updates ceased and I did a fresh install of 22.04.3. I am concerned that if I do not figure this out I may have to move distros which I am not wanting  to do. Also not sure that the same thing might happen with another distro. Thank you for your help